# Spinner return default number when i write comma

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, spinner

the problem is that since i write comma in my spinner and then i spin, the value return automatically to default(min or max) number, is there any solution to make it like this:when the user writes comma ,the spinner convert it automatically to point and spin normal to the next value.

```
var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    step: 0.25,
    min: -12,
    max: 8
});
```

here u can check it: http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/246/
I hope that i was enough clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding to your question is correct than you can use jquery ui spinner [change event](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change).

*Note*: here i handled only a single comma case, now you get the point and you can modify it acccording to your need.

```
var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    step: 0.25,
    min: -12,
    max: 8,
    change: function( event, ui ) {
      var value = $(event.target).val();
      value = value.replace(/,/,'.');
      $(event.target).val(value);
    }
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/247/)

Comment: ok it looks fine but when i spin it return to the default number or when i write the number per hand it dont work also

Comment: ok i got it, its because when you write in input field something like `1,2` and without focusing out you are spinning the value thats the issue, try to first focus out and than spin, than it will not show the default value

Comment: to resolve this issue you can use `spin start event` in which you can manually trigger focusout on the field

Comment: yes like this fine but the solution is not totally comfortable for the user and surely for a beginner